# how to update cluster status in dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I changed my initialization script after creating a cluster with 2 worker nodes for spark. Then I changed the script a bit and tried to update the cluster with 2 more worker nodes. The script failed because I simply forgot to `apt-get update` before `apt-get install`, so dataproc reports error and the cluster's status changed to ERROR. When I try to reduce the size back to 2 nodes again, it doesn't work anymore with the following message

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.update) Cluster 'cluster-1' must be running before it can be updated, current cluster state is 'ERROR'.
```

The two worker nodes are still added, but they don't seem to be detected by a running spark application at first because no more executors are added. I manually reset the two instances on the Google Compute Engine page, and then 4 executors are added. So it seems everything is working fine again except that the cluster's status is still ERROR, and I cannot increase or decrease the number of worker nodes anymore.

How can I update the cluster status back to normal (RUNNING)?

Answer (score 0):

In your case ERROR indicates that workflow to re-configure the cluster has failed, and Dataproc is not sure of its health. At this point Dataproc cannot guarantee that another reconfigure attempt will succeed so further updates are disallowed. You can however submit jobs.

Your best bet is to delete it and start over.

Comment: Can you elucidate what do you mean by another reconfigure?